# What is the pitch accent of ワロタ?

Tags: pitch-accent

What is the pitch accent for the Net slang term ワロタ? I've looked in the usual J-J dictionaries which have pitch accent info, but this doesn't seem to be a headword in any that I've seen.

My guesses would be 頭高 or 平板, but I've never heard the term read out, so I have no intuition here.

Comment: I personally pronounce it as same as あなた, and many other of my friend agrees me.

Comment: Its original accent in Kansai-ben is [わろた]【HLL】. Not sure how that slang word is pronounced when mixed in standard Japanese.

Comment: 「あなた」と同じってことは、 [ワロタ]{LHL} ってことですかね・・・？　私は[ワロタ]{HLL} だと思っていましたけど、関西人だから？

Comment: BTW I just checked, and this *is* a headword in the latest edition of daijirin! It lists it as heiban (but see naruto’s answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, it's always ワロタ【HLL】 (頭高) regardless of the dialect.

- [ワロタは英語で？ネット用語英訳してみた(榊原アリー)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf63rJkwK2Q&t=33s)
- [ワロタ の 日本語 の発音 - Forvo](https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BF/)

But it's not a word used in oral conversations, so not everyone is familiar with its typical pronunciation.

Comment: There seems to be some heiban on Youglish, what do you think of them? https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BF/japanese (use the dark blue arrow to see the next video)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Now I feel I have heard something like this before, but it still sounds a little off to me. There are words that were "flattened" recently by younger generations, but I'm not sure if this is one of them.

Comment: My 20-yr-old friend from Tokyo says it atamadaka and she normally heibanifies like everything possible lol, fwiw.